# How to validate a pydantic object after editing it

Tags: python, pydantic

Is there any obvious to validate a pydantic model after some changing some attribute?

Say I create a simple Model and object:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class A(BaseModel):
    b: int = 0

a=A()
```

Then edit it, so that it is actually invalid:

```py
a.b = "foobar"
```

Can I force a re-validation and expect a `ValidationError` to be raised?

I tried

```py
A.validate(a)                      # no error
a.copy(update=dict(b='foobar'))    # no error
```

What did work was

```
A(**dict(a._iter()))

ValidationError: 1 validation error for A
b
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
```

But that is not really straightforward *and* I need to use the supposedly private method `_iter`.

Is there a clean alternative?

Comment: Do you need only the pydantic library?  I made the data class for validation easier.  There's that: https://github.com/EvgeniyBurdin/validated_dc

Answer (score 26, accepted):

pydantic can do this for you, you just need [`validate_assignment`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/):

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class A(BaseModel):
    b: int = 0

    class Config:
        validate_assignment = True
```

Comment: Do you have any insights into the design decision regarding this? That is, why is `validate_assignment` (and `validate_all` for that matter) `False` by default? I'm a huge Pydantic fan but was a bit surprised to learn about this because I thought that Pydantic would be more, well, pedantic (at least by default)...

Comment: The problem I have with this is with root validators that validate multiple fields together. For example, I have a model with start/stop fields. In a root validator, I'm enforcing start<=stop. Say I initialize a model with start=1 and stop=2. I then want to change it to start=3 and stop=4. That's not possible (or it's cumbersome and hacky to resolve) because if I set start first, it will fail validation (start=3 stop=2).

Comment: @TaylorVance, I was stuck on that same question for a while as well. Finally came up with a couple approaches to address it that worked well for me. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75451357/16448566

Answer (score 5):

With Pydantic V2 you should use the `ConfigDict` to [configure](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/config/) the global behavior of your classes.
Usage of the `Config` class is still supported, but [deprecated](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/config/).

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict

class A(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(validate_assignment=True)
    b: int = 0
```

Comment: Hi. Since this was apparently resolved a long time ago, it should be useful to comment on how your post complements or updates the accepted answer.